# Unable to connect to MongoDb using Pentaho PDI CE

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am new to Pentaho. I am trying to read data from MongoDB using Pentaho Data Integration Community Edition. While trying to execute the MongoDB input step, I am getting the authentication failed error. I found that, the error was due to the missing MongoDb driver in PDI.

Later, I have downloaded the mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar file and added it to the location E:\pdi-ce-6.0.1.0-386\data-integration\lib. But still the problem persists.

While trying to get the Dbs by providing the MongoDb connection details in Pentaho MongoDb Input step, I am getting the error java.nullpointerException.

Could someone please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Error message while trying to get DBs by providing valid Mongo Server details in **Spoon**:

```
Unable to connect to MongoDB - check connection details : 'ok' should never be null...
```

Error Details and the stacktrace of a possibly exception:

```
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'ok' should never be null...
'ok' should never be null...

    at org.pentaho.mongo.wrapper.NoAuthMongoClientWrapper.getDatabaseNames(NoAuthMongoClientWrapper.java:358)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.mongodbinput.MongoDbInputDialog.setupDBNames(MongoDbInputDialog.java:1442)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.mongodbinput.MongoDbInputDialog.access$300(MongoDbInputDialog.java:82)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.mongodbinput.MongoDbInputDialog$4.widgetSelected(MongoDbInputDialog.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.mongodbinput.MongoDbInputDialog.open(MongoDbInputDialog.java:1079)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:124)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:8797)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:3027)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1316)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7979)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9310)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:654)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'ok' should never be null...
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.ok(CommandResult.java:43)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:109)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$NativeAuthenticator.authenticate(DBPort.java:545)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.authenticate(DBPort.java:322)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.checkAuth(DBPort.java:333)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:243)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:261)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:243)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:300)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getDatabaseNames(Mongo.java:384)
    at org.pentaho.mongo.wrapper.NoAuthMongoClientWrapper.getDatabaseNames(NoAuthMongoClientWrapper.java:353)
```

Comment: Is your mongodb database located on another server ?

Comment: yes.. MongoDB is hosted in another active server.

Comment: Which version of PDI do you use ?

Comment: Can you give the error message ?

Comment: @maximilienAndile.Please find the error message details in the above updated post. Also PDI version is 6.0.1.0-386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB input step, configuring connection with just server host name, without specifying username and password, resolves the issue.. !!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Aarthi Priyadharshini - to get this done, I found a link here that shows you exactly what to do - http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Read+Data+From+MongoDB

Since MongoDB is a Big Data platform, it is found under the big data options in the Design view. Watch the video on the link to learn exactly how to use.

Comment: In spoon, new database connection, provides with a list of a options, but not for MongoDB. Could you please help me with the steps to create it?

Comment: Hi Aarthi Priyadharshini - to get this done, I found a link here that shows you exactly what to do - http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Read+Data+From+MongoDB

Since MongoDB is a Big Data platform, it is found under the big data options in the Design view. Watch the video on the link to learn exactly how to use.

Comment: I did exactly as mentioned in the above link, but it is of no help. Even I tried downloading another version of PDI(pdi-ce-5.0.1.A-stable) from the same link, but still issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem downloading the last versions of PDI

http://ci.pentaho.com/view/Data%20Integration/job/Kettle/

Contains auth with mongo 3.2.2  and works!

Is not for production enviroments!